# escaping single-quote in double quotes in another double quote

Tags: javascript, php

My code is the following

```
<button onClick="showMoveFile(<?php echo $file_id; ?>, 
\"<?php echo $folder_id; ?>\", 
\"<?php echo addslashes($filename); ?>");\">
   move
</button>
```

the onClick event is already in double-quotes.

the **filename** and **folder_id** are strings.

The problem begins when **$filename** has an apostrophe in it, like **cousin's**

For some reason, I cannot escape the 'as I should.

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this, use `addslashes` to escape for js
the `\\` in the path are required to escape for php
Usually pathnames use `/` to avoid the double escaping

```
<?php
$file_id = "abc";
$folder_id = 'folder';
$filename = "cousin's";
?>

<button onClick='showMoveFile("<?php echo addslashes("$file_id\\$folder_id\\" . $filename); ?>");'>move</button>
```

For me that outputs

```
<button onClick='showMoveFile("abc\\folder\\cousin\'s");'>move</button>
```